# Multi Domain PHP Post and Redirection

Tags: php

There are many similar questions on the same. I have tried to look far and even tried using the comments and suggestions provided for the similar questions but I am stuck. I can't achieve what I want to.

Both domains are owned by me (Abc.com and xyz.com) and I have full right/access on them

- User Enters Name, College, Amount in a form on Abc.com
- I need to post the result to xyz.Com/abc.php
- Notify user " Being redirected to xyz.com for further process"
- Redirect the user to xyz.Com/abc.php
- On xyz.Com/abc.php, User is showed the posted values (received values from Abc.com)

These are the things I tried and came to know:

- I know curl is for posting only, it can't redirect
- Header() redirects but post?? I think No.
- Using session variables work on same domain not on domain to domain

What should be the process to achieve this. There ought to be some way to achieve this.

Comment: Can I use Database to store the received value by curl and generate a unique id and return that. That id is appended to header or redirect and the page re queries the database using the url appended id and shows the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on abc.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function redirectWarn() {
    alert("Now redirecting you to xyz.com for final processing!");}
</script>

<form method="POST" action="xyz.com/abc.php">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="text" id="college" name="college">
  <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="redirectWarn();">
</form>
```

Then when the user clicks submit, the alert tells them they are being redirected to xyz.com/abc.php. In that file on that server (xyz.com/abc.php) you need to get the user data by inserting this PHP at the top of the file abc.php:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $college = $_POST['college'];
  $amount = $_POST['amount'];
?>
```

Please make sure that you use some kind of javascript on abc.com or PHP on xyz.com to make sure that the user has entered data into your form fields before they get redirected. Also, if you are going to put these values into a database query or otherwise use them elsewhere, promise the internet that you will sanitize these values so your site won't get hacked and turned into a malware distribution center. :)